# move [nwp] tag to [numerical-weather-prediction]

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging, tag-synonyms

Move [nwp](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nwp) tag to [numerical-weather-prediction](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerical-weather-prediction). Initialised tags are unclear, even when the initialism is common. I can't suggest a synonym, because I don't have points in that tag.

Comment: I agree. This makes sense.

Comment: This makes sense... but "a tag cannot be longer than 25 characters". :(

Comment: @hichris123: Bah, I thought it might be something like that. I wonder if it might be worth adding [tag:numerical-weather] or something, to help clarify it in the tag list?

Comment: I agree about acronyms being unclear in general, but I think this is one where we should make an exception. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Please keep [nwp](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nwp). It is brief, clear and refers to a very specific aspect of atmospheric modeling. Should not be confused with [weather-modelling](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weather-modelling), as it is a more defined subset of the latter.

The term "nwp" is deeply engrained in the meteorological community and is even an item in the [AMS Glossary](http://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/Nwp). If the acronym is unclear, the description of the tag should be helpful to most readers.

Comment: Looks like it won't change anyway... part of the problem is that the except on http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/tags has the "NWP or Numerical Weather Prediction is" part cut off. I have tried to edit the excerpt to prevent the to prevent the expanded version being cut off "NWP is Numerical Weather Prediction: ...", but I don't know if it will work.

Comment: I agree with this.  To be a tag synonym the meaning of the words should by synonyms.  The only tag I can think of to would be [tag:numerical-wx-prediction] but that depends on yet another acronym which isn't as formalized as nwp.  Also note that NWP appears in the list at http://www2.ametsoc.org/ams/index.cfm/publications/authors/journal-and-bams-authors/author-resources/list-of-acronyms-and-abbreviations/ which means NWP is considered common enough that it need not be defined in articles published in AMS journals.

Answer (score -1):

How about [weather-modelling](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weather-modelling)

(given the 25-char restriction, numerical-weather-prediction isn't an option.)

Answer (score -1):

[numerical-met-prediction](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerical-met-prediction) could work

(given the 25 char restriction, numerical-weather-prediction isn't an option.)

Comment: [tag:digital-cloud-forecast]?